# Formulario múltiple Gravity Forms

Tags: php, html, wordpress

estoy realizando un formulario múltiple, me explico:

**Un formulario que cuando rellenas los campos y seleccionas el botón continuar te lleve a otro formulario, pero guardando los datos del formulario anterior.**

He leído que se puede hacer con sesiones con php, pero en este tema de wordpress estoy usando el plugin GRAVITY FORMS, y quisiera saber si alguien conoce la forma de cómo hacerlo con este plugin.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

Gravity Form permite "Dinamic Population", que esta bastante cerca de lo que pides.

De manera general, primero tendrás que marcar la opción "Permitir al campo rellenarse dinámicamente" en los campos de formulario receptor, y luego enviarle los datos, ya sea por post, shortcode o similar.

La documentación de Gravity Form lo detalla bastante bien en:
https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/using-dynamic-population/

Comment: Recomiendo que agregues un ejemplo de tu respuesta, los enlaces externos tienden a fallar